# JQuery validation fires on a 1st form only out of 3

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-validate

I have a bit of a problem working with JQuery validation with Jquery validate plugin.
Things were working fine until I changed my layout and added bootstrap toggle elements on forms. There are multiple forms on my views and they are put into a parent div, every form has a heading, clicking upon which I get the form toggled.

So it's something like this.

```
CreateFormDiv
  MainFormToCreateAReacord

Parent div - accordion
   form-div1 - parent accordion
     form1 
   form-div2 - parent accordion
     form2
```

Now when I click on `form-div1` I get the `form1` and I'm able to successfully update a record. When I click on `form-div2` I get the `form2` and `form1` hides and i can update `form2` now.

All this works fine but the problem comes when I have the `MainFormToCreateAReacord` opened (meaning not hidden). While thats opened and when I try to submit `form1`, it validates the `MainFormToCreateAReacord` which is not right as I submitted `form1` and it should validate `form1` and not `MainFormToCreateAReacord`[image]

I attached the screenshot just to make it clear.

Here is the jsfiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/9h7qrcg6/1/)

In the fiddle example, it appears that the validation works on the item no 74 but not on 75 & 76.

Any pointers on the same will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check **WORKING [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9h7qrcg6/3/)**

jQuery validate binds validation To Only 1 Form At A time , so if u use ONLY 1 class for validation , then validation applied to only 1st Form :)

Just give DIFFERENT class to Each form and now write validate() for Each. :)

//Html

```
<div class="all-keys">
  <section class="innerContent">
    <h3>
      SSH Keys
      <a class="btn btn-info sshNew" data-toggle="collapse" href="#ssh_form">
        Add SSH Key
      </a>
    </h3>
    <div class="whiteContainer panel-collapse collapse in" id="ssh_form" style="">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/ssh_keys" class="new_ssh_key1" data-remote="true" id="sshForm" method="post" novalidate="novalidate"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"></div>  <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" cols="2" id="ssh_key_key" name="ssh_key[key]" placeholder="Public SSH Key" required="required" rows="2"></textarea>
            <input id="ssh_key_id" name="ssh_key[id]" type="hidden">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" name="button" type="submit">Create SSH Key</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-group margin-top10" id="accordionSSH">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <div class="pull-right text-right">
              <a class="fa fa-edit sshEdit" data-parent="#accordionSSH" data-toggle="collapse" href="#sshKey74Edit"></a>
              <a class="fa fa-close" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" href="/ssh_keys/74" rel="nofollow"></a>
            </div>
            <a class="sshEdit" data-parent="#accordionSSH" data-toggle="collapse" href="#sshKey74">
              74
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="sshKey74">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-control" disabled="" placeholder="Name of key" type="text" value="74">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <textarea class="form-control" cols="2" disabled="" rows="2">Some key</textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="sshKey74Edit">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/ssh_keys/74" class="edit_ssh_key1" data-remote="true" id="sshForm" method="post" novalidate="novalidate"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="patch"></div>  <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" cols="2" id="ssh_key_key" name="ssh_key[key]" placeholder="Public SSH Key" required="required" rows="2"></textarea>
                <input id="ssh_key_id" name="ssh_key[id]" type="hidden" value="74">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" name="button" type="submit">Update SSH Key</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <div class="pull-right text-right">
              <a class="fa fa-edit sshEdit" data-parent="#accordionSSH" data-toggle="collapse" href="#sshKey75Edit"></a>
              <a class="fa fa-close" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" href="/ssh_keys/75" rel="nofollow"></a>
            </div>
            <a class="sshEdit" data-parent="#accordionSSH" data-toggle="collapse" href="#sshKey75">
              75
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="sshKey75">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-control" disabled="" placeholder="Name of key" type="text" value="75">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <textarea class="form-control" cols="2" disabled="" rows="2">some key </textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="sshKey75Edit">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/ssh_keys/75" class="edit_ssh_key2" data-remote="true" id="sshForm" method="post" novalidate="novalidate"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="patch"></div>  <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" cols="2" id="ssh_key_key" name="ssh_key[key]" placeholder="Public SSH Key" required="required" rows="2"></textarea>
                <input id="ssh_key_id" name="ssh_key[id]" type="hidden" value="75">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" name="button" type="submit">Update SSH Key</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <div class="pull-right text-right">
              <a class="fa fa-edit sshEdit" data-parent="#accordionSSH" data-toggle="collapse" href="#sshKey84Edit"></a>
              <a class="fa fa-close" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" href="/ssh_keys/84" rel="nofollow"></a>
            </div>
            <a class="sshEdit" data-parent="#accordionSSH" data-toggle="collapse" href="#sshKey84">
              84
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="sshKey84">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-control" disabled="" placeholder="Name of key" type="text" value="84">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <textarea class="form-control" cols="2" disabled="" rows="2">Some key</textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="sshKey84Edit">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/ssh_keys/84" class="edit_ssh_key3" data-remote="true" id="sshForm" method="post" novalidate="novalidate"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="patch"></div>  <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" cols="2" id="ssh_key_key" name="ssh_key[key]" placeholder="Public SSH Key" required="required" rows="2"></textarea>
                <input id="ssh_key_id" name="ssh_key[id]" type="hidden" value="84">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" name="button" type="submit">Update SSH Key</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

//jQuery part

```
$(".new_ssh_key1").validate();
$(".edit_ssh_key1").validate();
$(".edit_ssh_key2").validate();
$(".edit_ssh_key3").validate();

$(".sshEdit").click(function(){
if(!$(".sshNew").hasClass("collapsed"))
      $(".sshNew").trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: While that works, I'm curious to know why would such a thing happen. These forms are always present on the view so given a class in to validate a form, it should also validate other forms with the same class names. I mean at least this is how it was working earlier for me. May I know what makes it behave differently ?

Comment: jQuery validate binds validation To Only 1 Form At A time , so if u use ONLY 1 class for validation , then validation applied to only 1st Form :)

Comment: it wants each Form to be Uniquely identified.

Comment: Thanks for your quick help. I appreciate your time :)

Comment: @PamioSolanky , Also in your HTML id `sshForm` come 3 times . ID MUST be unique. You can do +1 if it solves ur problem Thanks